# Insert with missing column not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two queries in my `PHP` file:

```
$q1 = " INSERT INTO team_password ( team_name, password ) VALUES ( '". $team_name."', '". $password."' )";  
$result = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
```

it is working fine.

```
$q2 = " INSERT INTO all_users ( user_name, team_name ) VALUES ('". $user_name."', '". $team_name."')";

$all_users_var = $mysqli_query($con,$q2);
```

But this query is not responding.
all_users have `four columns` user_name, team_name, longitude and latitude.
longitude and latitude have `default` have values `NULL`.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$mysqli_query` - why sigil (`$`) there?

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Did you declare this columns in your database as Nullable? (Uncheck the Not null)

Comment: What does "not responding" mean?

Comment: May I ask you to delete this question? It adds nothing to the site.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this as the damage caused by an unescaped variable could be severe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the guilty here is the `$` sign before your `mysqli_query()`.

When you have a doubt, you should check your php_error.log  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the `$` sign before `mysqli_query()` which is creating problems, remove `$` sign and execute the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q2 = " INSERT INTO all_users ( user_name, team_name ) VALUES ('$user_name','$team_name')";

$all_users_var = mysqli_query($con,$q2);
```

or this one

```
$q2 = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO all_users(user_name, team_name) VALUES('$user_name','$team_name')") or die(mysqli_error());
```